# How to return variable from external module

Tags: python, return, ib-api

While using the interactive brokers api python library,
I try to return a dict object from specific functions in my program that supported by the ibapi module itself.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
from threading import Timer
from threading import *
import csv
import storage_handler as sh
from contractstock import stock
import datetime
import os
import foldernavigator as fn

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId ):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        group = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 35, 37, 57, 75]
        i = 0
        while i < len(group):
                data = {}
                data['reqId'] = reqId
                data[TickTypeEnum.to_str(tickType)] = size
                print(str(data)
                return data
            i += 1
 
    def start(self):
        fn.foldercreator(self)
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = stock["symbol"]
        contract.secType = stock["secType"]
        contract.exchange = stock["exchange"]
        contract.currency = stock["currency"]
        contract.primaryExchange = stock["primaryExchange"]

        self.reqMarketDataType(4)

        self.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])
        self.reqMktData(2, contract, "", False, False, [])
        self.reqMktData(3, contract, "", False, False, [])
        self.reqMktData(4, contract, "", False, False, [])

        ids1 = [0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,49,85]
        ids2 = [[21,165],[46,236],[48,233],[54,293],[55,294],[56,295],[63,595],[64,595],[65,595],[89,236]]

        for i in ids1:
            self.reqMktData(str(i), contract, "", False, False, [])

        for j in ids2:
            self.reqMktData(str(j[0]), contract, str(j[1]), False, False, [])
    
    def stop(self):        
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect() 

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

While I use the `return` statement in order to get the dict object I can't seem to figure out what is the object path after the return from the function.
How can I return objects from external functions back to my main program?

- the "def tickPrice" is the call back from the line "self.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])"
  that get back NONE if i put it in variable

Comment: Where did you want to return something to where? I didn't quite get that.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i forgot to mention that the "def tickPrice" is the call back from the line "self.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])"